# How to get a <span> value to google extension from a web page

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I need to get this value to my google extension popup constantly or next 10 seconds(with a loop) from a web page which is going to be the current tab.

```
<span id="serverTime">7:55:37</span>
```

I have got this far by now;

**popup.html**

```
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><a id="submit" onclick="getTime();">Time</a>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label id="time">---</label>
        </td>
        </tr>

<script src="time.js"></script>
```

**time.js**

```
function getTime() {
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { code: "var serverTime = document.getElementById('serverTime')" });

}); }
```

**manifest.json**

```
    {
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "MyExtension",
  "description": "Google Extension",
  "version": "1.0",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "css": [ "popup.css" ],
      "js": [ "time.js" ],
      "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "all_frames":  true
    }
  ],

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "klanlar.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "persistent":  false,
    "script": [ "time.js" ]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>",
    "notifications",
    "tabs"
  ]

}
```

I cannot make the serverTime get back to extension popup, is there any chance you all can help please

**UPDATED time.js**

```
function getTime() {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tab) {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, { code: "var serverTime = document.getElementById('serverTime').value.toString(); alert(serverTime);" });
        document.getElementById("time").value = serverTime;

    });
}
```

still doesnt gets the value or pops up any alert

Answer (score 1):

`var serverTime = document.getElementById('serverTime')` only gets the element. You want to get the value

```
var serverTime = document.getElementById('serverTime').value
```

Comment: I added an updated time.js but still doesn't work, or shows an alert. Thank you for your correction tho

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of using

```
var serverTime = document.getElementById('serverTime')
```

you should use this one

```
var serverTime = document.getElementById("serverTime").innerText
```

Comment: Hey there, try to complete your answer and cover all of his questions. Like the alert part and comunicating back to the extension. That way it can be marked as accepted and will also help others. Otherwise people may downvote your answer and lower your reputation. I'm not a chrome addon-developer myself, so I don't have the solution.